Is there any way to retrieve paypal subscription list programmatically?
I am seeking to retrieve paypal subscription list but there is no way to get subscription list programmatically...
The way that i found is using transaction search api but this is only working on subscriptions for which actual payments have occurred, not free trial.
Has anyone figured out a way?
how to get paypal subscription list

There is no API to retrieve subscriptions. A list of Subscriptions can be viewed at https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans , but apart from that you are expected to keep a record of subscriptions in your own database, generally by receiving webhooks: BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED (only needed for trials) and PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED (for everything else)
